# Pension Rollover Problem

Tags: retirement, pension, rollover

A friend of mine had a deadline of 2/17 to make a decision about the distribution of her pension that needed to be rolled over.  She missed the deadline.  Fidelity automatically chose one for her and she is not happy about their choice - a monthly distribution which terminates upon demise (heirs get nothing).  She spoke with a Fidelity rep today who indicated that the decision is final.

I have no experience with pensions so all I could come up with were generic suggestions:

- Speak to another rep
- See if there is an appeal process
- Contact the former employer to see if they offer in house support for retirees

I'd appreciate it if anyone can provide more substantive direction that might help her resolve this problem.  TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "chose one"? Do you mean that they gave her a lump sum or set up a recurring payment?  What did they choose that she doesn't like?

Comment: Recurring payment with no death benefit (added that to the question).  That's the sum total of info provided to me.

Comment: I think speaking to another rep will not help, but asking about appeal processes and contacting the employer might. Usually though once a choice is made it is hard to revert, so better not to miss deadlines.